# Hive CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE with parameterized LOCATION

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

This works as expected:

```
 DROP TABLE mytable; 
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mytable (
     Dim1 STRING,
     Dim2 STRING,
     Dim3 STRING ) 
 LOCATION 'hdfs:///user/myuser/data';
```

but this doesn't:

```
 set rootpath = 'hdfs:///user/myuser/data'; 
 DROP TABLE mytable; 
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mytable (
     Dim1 STRING,
     Dim2 STRING,
     Dim3 STRING ) 
 LOCATION '${hiveconf:rootpath}';
```

It fails with the following error (Hive 0.9.0):

> FAILED: Parse Error: line 9:11 mismatched input 'hdfs' expecting EOF near ''''

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a known issue/limitation? Are there any suggestions for workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should read `LOCATION ${hiveconf:rootpath}`.

Comment: Doh!  Can't believe I didn't catch that one.  <hangs head in shame>
Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an environment variable which we often use in the create table DDL's. It can be referred as ${env:variable_name}