# Create table with parameterized location

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

This is for Hive 1.1.0 with Cloudera 5.4.8.

I've tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382342/hive-create-external-table-with-parameterized-location), however it doesn't seem to work for me. I've tried something like the following via "hive -e" and with a script file:

```
set rootpath = 'hdfs:///user/myuser/data'; 
DROP TABLE mytable; 
CREATE [EXTERNAL] TABLE mytable (
     Dim1 STRING,
     Dim2 STRING,
     Dim3 STRING ) 
 LOCATION ${hiveconf:rootpath};
```

I just get the error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:126 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting     StringLiteral near 'LOCATION' in table location specification
```

Is there anything that I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some minor changes are needed in your script

```
set hiveconf:rootpath='hdfs:///user/myuser/data'; 
DROP TABLE mytable; 
CREATE [EXTERNAL] TABLE mytable (
     Dim1 STRING,
     Dim2 STRING,
     Dim3 STRING ) 
 LOCATION '${hiveconf:rootpath}';
```

Comment: Which happens to be the exact opposite answer to the linked question. However as I found out via the oozie mailing list, it is the correct way. Thank you for the reply.